# MapServer can't draw PostGIS table

Tags: postgresql, mapserver, ms4w

I'm using MS4W 3.0.6 (MapServer CGI 6.0.3), PostgreSQL 13 with geospatial extension (PostGIS) and pmapper 4.3.2. I can display maps perfectly in MapServer and pmapper with shapefiles, but when I try to display a PostgreSQL table I receive this message:

> msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'pozos_azc_12'. msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error executing query: ERROR: no existe la funciÃ³n st_force_2d(geometry) LINE 1: select encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force_2D("geom"),'NDR'),'hex') ... ^ HINT: Ninguna funciÃ³n coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiÃ³n explÃ­cita de tipos.*

I have a index file in table, the geometry column is `geom` and the PK are `gid` and in the database are the geospatial extension, I aislate the problem in a simple MapServer to see if it works, but it doesn't, my mapfile is:

```
MAP 
    NAME "hola"
    SIZE 400 300
    #IMAGECOLOR 249 245 186
    STATUS ON
    IMAGETYPE png
    EXTENT 477242.999953 2151985.999950 484110.999994 2157396.999950
    UNITS meters
    WEB
        TEMPLATE "plantilla1.html"
        IMAGEPATH "/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/"
        IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
    END 
    SYMBOLSET "symbols/symbols-pmapper.sym"
    FONTSET "fonts/msfontset.txt"
    SHAPEPATH "../data/"
    Symbol
      Name 'circle'
      Type ELLIPSE
      Filled TRUE
      Points
        1 1
      END
    END 
    LAYER
      NAME "pozos_azc_12"
      CONNECTIONTYPE postgis     
      CONNECTION "user=postgres password=Password dbname=database host=127.0.0.1 port=2022"
      DATA "geom FROM pozos_azc_12 USING UNIQUE gid USING SRID=4326"
      PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
      PROCESSING "FORCE2D=YES"
      STATUS DEFAULT
      TYPE point      
      CLASS
        COLOR 0 255 0
        SYMBOL 'circle'
        SIZE 4
      END
    END
END
```

Maybe its a problem of compatibility with PG and MAPSERVER but if I update MapServer to the latest version, I understand pmapper doesn't work with MS4W 4.x

I don't know what I was doing wrong or how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Try to remove FORCE2D=YES, the error message refers to missing st_force_2d function.

Comment: Thanks for your soon anwer, i will remove the FORCED2D but there is no change, i recive the same message:msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'pozos_azc_12'. msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error executing query: ERROR: no existe la funciÃ³n st_force_2d(geometry) LINE 1: select encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force_2D("geom"),'NDR'),'hex') ... ^ HINT: Ninguna funciÃ³n coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiÃ³n explÃ­cita de tipos.    thanks and i try to search more about it, regards

Comment: The current MapServer code is checking the PostGIS version https://github.com/MapServer/MapServer/blob/af4b696067666849eb735896dd91d6fa1a273f03/mappostgis.cpp#L1673. But if you must work with pmapper and use MapServer 6.x that is unmaintained then perhaps you must try to install an ancient PostGIS as well. But I really believe that pmapper is dead https://www.pmapper.net/. If you want to know the current status ask from Mapgears who developed it https://mapgears.com/en/.

Comment: yes im afraid not use pmapper any more and use another app with the same pmapper tools and learn it faster, do you now some one?. thanks for your answer and support, i try to do something about it thanks so much

Comment: I've had to create custom builds for these types of p.mapper issues in the past for organizations (I am the developer of MS4W), and that is always an option for you (contact my company: GatewayGeo).  p.mapper was created by Armin Burger, and you are correct that it does not run with newer MS4W series.  Since you are using MS4W you should take a look at GeoMoose, or Mapbender, both come with MS4W and are similar to p.mapper.  (you can demo them on the MS4W dev server at https://ms4w.dev ).  Hope that helps!  And thanks for using MS4W.  "open doors as well as Windows" -jeff

Comment: i really apreciate your supoort and gide, i will be check both options that you give,us, another question, can i have MS4W series 3.x in one port and MS4W 4.x series in other port and use it independient? or MS4W only can live one version in one computer or server?, again.. thanks for all

Comment: yes that setup works well (different Apache ports on same machine).

Comment: Thanks so much, then i try that and try to don´t loose my last developpments and migrate to the newest versions at the same time, thanks for every thing and for your atention, do you now about a tutorial to setup MS4W in diferents ports, thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message that tells that PostgreSQL/PostGIS does not have a  ST_Force_2D("geom"). PostGIS does have another function with almost same name https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force2D.html. The manual page has a note:

```
Changed: 2.1.0. Up to 2.0.x this was called ST_Force_2D.
```

It seems that your old MapServer version does not play together with your PostGIS version. You could have a try by commenting out the line that triggers the use of this function but if you have XYZ or XYM or XYZM geometries in the database they may cause some trouble. Anyway, try with this edit

```
# PROCESSING "FORCE2D=YES"
```

Comment: Thanks for your soon answer, i try to edit the "processing" line but it still the same error, even i try to import the SHP file with "generate simple geometries" option in PG shape import tool and the error persist, maybe i have to use new version of mapserver and forgot pmapper, thanks so much for your atention